# python - printing result of for loop the not-usual way?

Tags: python

The following code snippet:

```
i = 3

for i in range(1, i+1):

  for j in range (1, i+1):
    print j
```

outputs:

```
 1
 1
 2
 1
 2
 3
```

but the output I want is:

```
 1
 1 2
 1 2 3
```

Comment: at each step, you only print one digit per line + do not use `i` for looping since it's already a variable you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `print j,` to keep the output in the same line, then `print` at the end of each row to get to the row below:

```
i = 3

for i in range(1, i+1):
    for j in range (1, i+1):
        print j,
    print
```

---

- I would suggest, as a note, the better, python3 compatible version:

  ```
  rows = 5
  for row_max in range(1, rows+1):
      print(' '.join(str(j) for j in range(1, row_max+1)))
  ```